# Why alphabetical sorting on numeric inputs?

Tags: javascript, string, sorting

Why is this function returning elements sorted alphabetically rather than numerically?  I get the identical results whether I use `Number` or `ParseFloat`.

```
function sortMe() {
  var x = ["1.0","2.5", "11.0"];
  var y = x.map(Number);
  Logger.log(y.sort());
}
```

Result: `1,11,2.5`

Answer (score 2):

Because [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts alphabetical, so `'11'` comes before `'2'`.

> The **`sort()`** method sorts the elements of an array [in place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) and returns the array. The sort is not necessarily [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.

To overcome this problem, you could use a numerical sort with a callback, like

```
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
});
```

Comment: Oy.  Apparently this is [how it's done properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21595293/403455).

Answer (score 1):

That's because the default sort order is according to string Unicode code points, no matter what your input is. Your `Number` are implicitly converted back to strings and then sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Its not that you are unable to pass a numeric array, whatever you pass `Array#sort` will try to compare on the basis of their unicode representation. Instead pass a comparator, to compare how you want to compare while sorting

```
y.sort((a,b)=>a-b)
```

Answer (score -1):

The [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method sorts the items of an array.

The sort order can be either alphabetic or numeric, and either ascending (up) or descending (down).

By default, the sort() method sorts the values as strings in alphabetical and ascending order, with respect to each element's [Unicode](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) point value.

Have a look at this example:

```
var fruit = ['cherries', 'apples', 'bananas'];
fruit.sort(); // ['apples', 'bananas', 'cherries']

var scores = [1, 10, 21, 2]; 
scores.sort(); // [1, 10, 2, 21]
// Note that 10 comes before 2,
// because '10' comes before '2' in Unicode code point order.

var things = ['word', 'Word', '1 Word', '2 Words'];
things.sort(); // ['1 Word', '2 Words', 'Word', 'word']
// In Unicode, numbers come before upper case letters,
// which come before lower case letters.
```

Comment: Order can be either "default" or "whatever you program in your sort function". There's no special settings for "numeric" or "ascending/descending".